# Problem related to recursion in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I was trying to solve a [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) problem when I encountered an issue.

```js
let arr: number[] = []
function inorder(tree: BST | null): void {
    if(tree !== null) {
        inorder(tree.left)
        arr.push(tree.value)
        inorder(tree.right)
    }
}
```

The above function should be returning an array which contains elements in sorted order because of inorder traversal. However it is not behaving as expected.

To get around the issue, what I did is instead of mutating the array, I changed the recursive function to return a new array eveytime. In that case it seems to work as expected i.e final returned array is sorted.

Why is this happening?  Is this related to asynchronous behaviour of Javascript. If so what is the proper explanation?

Comment: Um, this should work this way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. As you are just mutating the `arr`, post `inorder()` you can print it. Else you just wrap another function on top of `inorder` and return `arr` at the end of the function.

```
let arr: number[] = []
interface BST{
  left:BST | null,
  right:BST | null,
  value:number
}
function inorder(tree: BST | null): void {
  if(tree !== null) {
      inorder(tree.left)
      arr.push(tree.value)
      inorder(tree.right)
  }
}

const bstData: BST={
  left:{
    left:{
      left:null,
      right:null,
      value:3
    },
    right:{
      left:null,
      right:null,
      value:7
    },
    value:5
  },
  right:{
    left:{
      left:null,
      right:null,
      value:15
    },
    right:{
      left:null,
    right:null,
    value:25
    },
    value:20
  },
  value:10
}
inorder(bstData)
console.log(arr)
```

**Edit 1:** Creating a wrapper function

```
function inorderWrapper(tree: BST | null) {
    let arr: number[] = []
    function inorder(tree: BST | null): void {
        if (tree !== null) {
            inorder(tree.left)
            arr.push(tree.value)
            inorder(tree.right)
        }
    }
    inorder(tree)
    return arr;
}

inorderWrapper(data)
```